# Solana Node syncing issue

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter, solana-cli, solana-test-validator, solana-pay

I have setup a solana node on my ubuntu server , I am using devnet Url in my solana config file , on cli it is showing correct block-height transactions-count and everything is working according to devnet , but when i used my url on which solana-test-validator is running it is showing different block-height and transaction count. Tried a lot but still the issue is same , i need to used my this node for rpc request.
Need Help in this regard
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior -- `solana-test-validator` runs a complete independent local cluster, not associated to any other cluster like devnet.

If you want to run your own node connected to devnet, you can follow the instructions for running a validator at https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start.